# Why does Wordpress ajax die('0')

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I added the following to my functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_send_email', 'send_email_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_email', 'send_email_callback');
```

So i added the following callback function:

```
send_email_callback()
{
//do some processing
 echo json_encode(array('response'=>'Ya man it worked.'));
//return control back to *-ajax.php
}
```

This is what is returned to my javascript :

```
{"response":"Ya man it worked."}0
```

So ofcourse when it reaches the  $.parseJSON( msg ) line I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number.

```
  var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { action : 'send_email', P : container },
            dataType: "html"
        });

        request.done(function( msg ) {

           var obj = $.parseJSON( msg );
            console.log(obj.response);

        });

        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    });
```

So where does this 0 come from? **admin-ajax.php** 
it says on line 97:

```
// Default status
die( '0' );
```

Why is this here, why am I reaching the die('0') line? Shouldnt it be just die() so it doesnt mess up my response?

Seems the only way to fix this is either modify admin-ajax.php or simply die() at the end of my  send_email_callback() function.

Comment: I've never seen json_encode used that way.  What happens if you `return json_encode(array('response'=>'Ya man it worked.'));` instead?

Comment: @jonathan Sorry typed it out instead of pasting from the project you are correct that was a typo

Comment: Cool - only in your edit you added one to many opening parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WordPress AJAX actions, you aren't supposed to `return` the response, but `echo` the response and call `die` yourself. WordPress will continue to call all of the AJAX registered callbacks until one of the callbacks kills the execution, with the final one dieing with the response of `0`.

#### Example from WordPress Codec [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

```
<?php 

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever;

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

Comment: Sorry I mistyped that line I dont return from that context just echo it, which then proceeds to finish execution and still adds 0 onto the end of my reponse

Comment: @Edward I thought that might be the case. Anyhow, you still need to call `die`, `exit`, or `wp_die` to stop the callback list.

Comment: Ok I understand but doesnt `die()` end the callback meaning i dont return control back to `admin-ajax.php`?

Comment: @Edward Yes, that's usually what you want. The AJAX callback should only run until you output your content.